# How to replace before first forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string for example:

```
 "prop/items/option-1/value"
```

I want to replace before first forward slash. Expected output would be:

```
"newvalue/items/option-1/value
```

I could not find suitable Regex to replace this pattern, Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let regex = /^[^/]+/

let string = "prop/items/option-1/value"

console.log(string.replace(regex, 'newvalue'))
```

Here's the regex you need.

- `^` - match from start of string
- `[^/]+` - match one or more characters except for forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use substr

```js
const str = "prop/items/option-1/value";

// Use substr
const newStr = 'newvalue' + str.substr(str.indexOf('/'));

// Log
console.log(newStr);
```